# Android 6.0 automated granted permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

Does it possible to set permission "ON" on  new Android 6.0 ? It means without asking user for allow permission? Any examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. This is the purpose of the new android-permission-politics. Otherwise this would be useless.